# How do I change this variable into an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

I am writing code in c++ for a game in which a bucket controlled by the user collects raindrops with the same radius. I want to use an array to make each of the 16 raindrops a different size(radius). I have no clue how to change the variable into an array.

I am given a variable:

```
int radius = randomBetween( MARGIN / 4, MARGIN / 2 );
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You're probably going to want to use floats, but basically if I understand you correctly...

```
int size_in_elements = 16;
float *a= new float[size_in_elements];
float maxvalue = 100.0f; // this will be the maximum value to assign to each element
for(int i = 0; i < size_in_elements; i++)
{
    a[i] = fmodf((float)rand(), maxvalue);
}
delete[] a; // Don't forget the brackets here... delete[] is used for deleting arrays.
```

Hope I helped some

Comment: `std::vector` would be a much better choice than managing the array memory yourself.

Comment: I think he's still learning the ropes with the base language... not to get too involved in the std namespace.

Comment: There is little point in teaching a beginner to use `new []` and `delete []` rather than to use the standard library.

Comment: While it's true that auto memory management is great, some people have need to overload new and delete eventually. Good to understand how they're used, since they're so fundamental to the language.

Comment: Some people have need(ed) to overload new and delete, so beginners should be thrown in at the deep end when they know nothing about c++? More people need to start off by writing correct programs. Starting off with manual memory management is just asking for problems. This approach is one of the reasons there is so much bad C++ code out there.

Comment: Sorry, I started off programming embedded C. Memory management was key, low level. I still use the same principles. To me, new and delete are high level operators. Not exactly an advanced topic.

Comment: Just a FYI, `float a[] = new float[size_in_elements];` is not valid C++.

Comment: sorry, float *a = new float[size_in_elements]; But back to the point. Per your rationale, he might as well just drop C++ altogether and use .NET to ensure the highest possible level of memory management.

Comment: @KeyboardChimp: While your strawman argument is amusing, nobody is suggesting that he switch languages. What we _are_ claiming is that your answer should be a C++ answer, not an answer inspired by low-level embedded C.

Comment: ...of which new and delete are C++ operators? Are they not?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example that uses actual C++.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

std::mt19937 prng(seed);
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(MARGIN / 4, MARGIN / 2);
std::vector<int> radii(16);
std::generate(radii.begin(), radii.end(), std::bind(dist, std::ref(prng)));
```

Comment: @juanchopanza While in a real program it will be necessary to put at least the last statement in a function, constructor or destructor, I don’t think it’s necessary to do that in such a simple example, as the point is to demonstrate `<random>` and `std::generate`, not function definitions.